# Injectivity of scalar extensions $R_K(G) \longrightarrow R_{K'}(G)$

Tags: representation-theory

I don't understand the subsection 14.6 on scalar extensions in Serre's book on linear representations (see page 122). 
Let $G$ a finite group.
Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $K'$ be an extension of $K$.
Each $K[G]$-module $E$ defines by scalar extension a $K'[G]$-module $K' \otimes_K E$.
We thus obtain a homomorphism
    $$ \theta : R_K(G) \longrightarrow R_{K'}(G), [E] \longmapsto [K' \otimes_K E] $$
where $R_K(G)$ denote the Grothendieck group of the category of finitely generated $K[G]$-modules.
This homomorphism is an injection.

The proof goes as follows.
Let $S_K$ denote the set of isomorphism classes of simple $K[G]$-modules.
Then $(E)_{E \in S_K}$ is a basis of $R_K(G)$.
If $D_E = \mathrm{End}_{K[G]}(E)$, then
    $$ (*) \  R := K' \otimes_K D_E \simeq \prod \mathrm{M}_{s_i}(D_i) $$
where the $D_i$ are (skew ?) fields.
Each of the $D_i$ corresponds to a simple $K'[G]$-module $E'_i$ and
    $$ \theta([E]) = \sum s_i[E'_i]. $$
I don't understand this.
I guess that we are using the Wedderburn-Artin theorem to obtain (*).
Then $D_i^{s_i}$ is a simple $R$-module.
(1) Why $D_i$ corresponds to a simple $K'[G]$-module $E'_i$ ?
(2) Why do we have $\theta([E]) = \sum s_i[E'_i]$ ?

Comment: As we are in characteristic zero, then representations are determined by their characters. Characters are not affected by base-change. So why go through this rigmarole?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What do you do when you want to decompose a representation of an algebra other than a group algebra? The computation above is pedagogically valuable.